# /var got misteriously renamed in /var.1 on CentOS6 server

Tags: centos, security, centos6, server-crashes

On one of ours CentOS6 servers /var got renamed to /var.1 tonight (around 3.24 am) and a new empty /var folder was created. Not surprisingly, it crashed soon after that.

Circumstances:

- Over the last two days, we have been DDOS'd by botnet activity conducting an apparent reflection attack against a large local business (a major headhache, thank you)
- This (mail,name) server exposes imap(s) pop3(s) smtp(s), http(s) and 587 ports - all of them fortigate and fail2ban protected. All experienced unusual activity related to the previous point.
- The time of the accident is about the same of the standard cron maintainence activity

I am still poring over the logs. Because of the first point, malware would be an obvious suspect **except** that renaming /var is a pretty self-harming activity for some actor willing to take over the machine while concealing itself. So I am thinking at some maintainence task gone awry (such as a disk filling up during /var cleanup). However, I cannot think of anything that does similar shenanigans.

Anybody able to shed light?

TIA

Comment: Any useful info in the admin .bash_history files? Do you have a centralized log collector that you can search from, in case it was something malicious? If it were, they would most likely try to cover their tracks and remove relevant logs from the local server.

Answer (score 1):

So after some log perusal, it turns out no foul play was involved. Somebody made an editing snafu in a logrotate config file, about 15 days ago, for a monthly rotation 
( var log /stuff instead of /var/log/stuff). As luck had it, it kicked in during the DDOS, clouding the picture - though in truth the var**.1** thing should have given me pause much sooner. Thanks to all who bothered.